# I'm creating a game and using a onsubmit function call on a button to start the game. How can I make the game play again?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a game and using onsubmit so when I press a button it calls a function to start the game.  How can I make the game play again? Would I just return false to onsubmit and then press the same button again to restart the game?

Answer (score -1):

In a nutshell, that would work, yes. But you can build this many different ways. You could have a different part of the interface (e.g. a button that shows when the game ends) trigger replay, by calling the function you have to start the game.